# how do i store a user in a variable in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

so, I am running a boy scout server and for it, I am making a bot. we have been struggling to get everyone's real name for better organization. the bot will ask for their name and they will type !name Travis_c. then I want it to store their discord username in a variable and send me a message saying trullycool => Travis_C. with that information, it would be super simple to change their nickname on the server. I am running into issues with getting the user who sent the previous message, into a variable.
my code is

---

`

1. ```
      case 'name':
        name = args[1];
        const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "names");
        user = message.author()
        if(!channel) return;
        message.channel.send(`${user} => ${name}`)
   ```

`

---

I am having issues on user = message.author()
I know if I want to reply to something I do message.reply but that wouldn't work in my situation. thanks in advance!

Comment: message.author is not a method, therefore, you don't need to use (). `message.author` will do.

Answer (score 1):

`message.author` is not a function so there is no need for `()` at the end of it.